# Objective C/ Swift How to open a base64 url?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, base64, mobile-safari

Objective C/ Swift How to open a Base64 url?

Currently I am trying to request safari with a Base64 url. It is not working. When i execute this particular url on the Mac safari verison it works.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var NameText: UITextField!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

@IBAction func homeScreen(sender: AnyObject) {
    let name = self.NameText.text
    var html = "<p>" + name + "</p>"
    let plainData = (html as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let base64String = plainData!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
    let concat = "data:text/html;base64," + base64String
    print(concat)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: concat)!)
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Currently if I enter the name 'bob', it generates: data:text/html;base64,PHA+Ym9iPC9wPg==

Basically what I am trying to do is take a user's name and generate an HTML for it. But this particular URL is not opening in mobile Safari. Does anyone know why?

Thanks,
DaTechnoGuru

P.S: I usderstand both Obj C and Swift. If you have an Obj C solution please let me know.

EDIT: I just tried to manually input the url "data:text/html;base64,PHA+Ym9iPC9wPg==" into the safari simulator and it worked. But it is still programmatically not working. Seems like there is an issue around the openURL function. Anyone know about this?

EDIT: I think that this may have something to do with localhost. but i dont know.

Answer (score 0):

To open safari, the URL need to start with protocol ie. http://
There is a list of supported protocols from Apple documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/openURL: which includes http, https, tel, facetime, and mailto schemes.

I tried you code and added protocol in front of the string. and it takes me to safari ok.

```
let concat = "http://data:text/html;base64," + base64String
```

Comment: thanks, this took me to safari but it did not run the contents of the encoded html. Without using the app, the url (without the http protocol) works fine.